# Getting exception when trying to connect to parse server from Android

Tags: android, database, exception, heroku, parse-platform

I just started with database integration for the first time with my Android App Development training.

I'm using the Parse SDK through Heroku.

I've been struggling for ages to just get a simple app to make a successful transaction to my databse.

The database is definitely working, seeming that I tested it by following the url through my web browser and getting the expected output from the database.

My problem is when I try to use the `saveInBackground()` method I get an exception. The strange thing is when I log the exception's message, I get nothing. So I decided to print out the stack trace, but it doesn't help me much. I hope someone can help me by looking at it.

**My code**:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();

  // Enable Local Datastore.
  Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

  // Add your initialization code here
  Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .applicationId("HIDDEN_APPLICATION_ID")
        .clientKey(null)
        .server("https://instawilhelm.herokuapp.com/parse/")
  .build()
  );

  ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
  gameScore.put("score", 1337);
  gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
  gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
  gameScore.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
      public void done(ParseException e) {
          if (e == null) {
              Log.i("Parse Connection", "Save Succeeded");
          } else {
              Log.i("Parse Connection", "Save Failed");
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  });


  ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
  ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
  // Optionally enable public read access.
  // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
  ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
}
```

**My stack trace:**

```
10-31 00:41:34.345 26045-26045/com.parse.starter W/System.err: com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: 
10-31 00:41:34.346 26045-26045/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRequest.newTemporaryException(ParseRequest.java:279)
10-31 00:41:34.346 26045-26045/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRESTCommand.onResponseAsync(ParseRESTCommand.java:303)
10-31 00:41:34.346 26045-26045/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:137)
10-31 00:41:34.347 26045-26045/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:133)
10-31 00:41:34.347 26045-26045/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917)
10-31 00:41:34.347 26045-26045/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
10-31 00:41:34.347 26045-26045/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:908)
10-31 00:41:34.347 26045-26045/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:715)
10-31 00:41:34.347 26045-26045/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:726)
10-31 00:41:34.348 26045-26045/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:818)
10-31 00:41:34.348 26045-26045/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:806)
10-31 00:41:34.348 26045-26045/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917)
10-31 00:41:34.348 26045-26045/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
10-31 00:41:34.348 26045-26045/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
10-31 00:41:34.348 26045-26045/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: Presuming the app ID matches, and there's no client key as well, correct?  What do you see in the logs on heroku, and can you inspect the exception object in debugger and post what the exception is?

Answer (score 0):

Try using saveEventually instead of saveInBackground.  Saw a post that said it worked for someone else.